# Why are my functions undefined when I declared the type already?

Tags: c++, class

Hi I was just trying to learn separate Classes in C++. I don't know why my code is not working. 
So here is the main file code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Number.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Number key;
    key.setNumber(200);
    cout<<key.getNumber();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Class cpp functions file code

```
#include "Number.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Number::setNumber(int transfernumber)
    {
    privatenumber = transfernumber;
    }

int Number::getNumber()
    {
        return privatenumber;
    }
```

And here is the header file

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H


class Number
{
    public:
        Number();
        void setNumber(int transfernumber);
        int getNumber();
    private:
        int privatenumber;
};

#endif // NUMBER_H
```

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think your code is not working?

Comment: When I build the program in codeblocks it says that the different functions are undefined

Comment: Can you post the error message and indicate in your code what line the compiler says the error happened?

Comment: So this is the screen shot link https://gyazo.com/2dd8863b482f15abe249676d327d09e8

Comment: Ok. It looks like it is not linking your Number.o file, that must be a codeblocks setting. Unfortunately I never used it. Also I noticed you have not defined your constructor `Number::Number()` in your `Number.cpp` file.

Comment: Ugh codeblock is so dumb. I restarted the program and it worked for some reason.......thanks for your time though

Comment: Okay, I think I have it. You need to select your files `Number.h` and `Number.cpp`, *right-click* on them with the mouse and select "Add to active project". If you do that for each of them then it should fix your problem. Oh and you have to add a constructor in `Number.cpp` too.

Comment: do you possibly mean that you got *undefined reference to* when compiling?

Answer (score 2):

In your cpp file you need to define the default constructor for the Number class. For example:

```
Number::Number() : privatenumber(0) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test your example. The error happened for the `main.cpp` cannot found the `number.cpp`. You have three ways to solve it:

1. write your `main()` to the `number.cpp`, not a solo file.
2. complie the `main.cpp` with the linux command `gcc` or write a `Makefile`, instead of using codeblocks.
3. If you want to use the codeblocks for compiling, you should create a project, and then add your three files to the project. Now compile the `main.cpp`.

Use the three ways above, I think you will compile successfully.

BTW, you should add the `Number::Number()` 's implementation.